# can I run minecraft without x11?

Tags: command-line, xorg, minecraft

Is it possible to run Minecraft in a terminal without X11 running. I know this does not run by default, but can it be set up?

Comment: Are you trying to run a Minecraft server?

Comment: no just wondering just how fast it can run on my netbook

Answer (score 2):

Running Minecraft on directly on top of the kernel frame buffer is not possible to my knowledge, nor would it be in the developers interest since they would have to implement a lot of stuff themselves that is being done for them in X11 (like input management, display device management, ...). I don't think they are interested in that...

As you have indicated in the comments your *actual* goal is to make Minecraft run faster by removing layers. While the idea of getting rid of the X11 server might sound good it would hardly improve your framerate compared to using non-composited X11! If your window manager doesn't use compositing X11 will basically just redirect all OpenGL calls (what Minecraft uses for rendering) directly to the graphics card.

**How to disable compositing**

Some things to note:

- Compositing itself isn't necessarily bad for performance, just the way X11 does it sucks!
- Disabling it will cause transparent surfaces to be filled with black instead of whatever is *behind* them.
- Most desktops nowadays use compositing. In some of them (such as Ubuntu's default desktop Unity and GNOME Shell) you cannot disable compositing at all.

In Xubuntu/XFCE4:

- Open the "Window manager tweaks"
- Select the tab "Compositor"
- Uncheck "Enable display compositing"

In Kubuntu/KDE4:

You can disable compositing at any time by pressing `Alt+Shift+F12`. In the window management settings there are also some options to disable compositing when a matching application is running. Note however that compositing is automatically disabled when a single application runs in fullscreen mode on one screen. ([Source](http://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2011/04/turning-compositing-off-in-the-right-way/))